# How to get transactions from the newest dates with Node.JS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to be able to get data from the most recent transaction first in my mongodb database.
This gets the data but its not the most recent transaction.

here is what my code looks like

```
router.get("/get-transactionby-email/:email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }
    const trans = await Transaction.find({ email: req.params.email });
    res.status(200).json(trans);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

router.get("/get-credit-transaction/:email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }
    const trans = await Transaction.find(
      { email: req.params.email , debit : 0.00 },
      { narration: true, credit: true, amount: true }
    );
    res.status(200).json(trans);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

How do I go about this? How can i get the most recent transactions first from the database by date.

My model structure looks like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const transactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required:true,
    max: 255,
  },
  narration: {
    type: String,
    required:true,
    max: 255,
  },
  credit: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Number,
    required:true,
  },
  debit: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Number,
    required:true,
  },
  amount: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Number,
    required:true,
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Transactions',transactionSchema);
```

Comment: You can sort on `created_at`

Comment: @HassanImam, Pls can you be of assistance with a snippet. New to this, so I do not make mistakes

Comment: `await Transaction.find({ email: req.params.email }).sort({created_at: -1})`